# Top 10%/Bottom 10% Conditional Format from Excel in Power BI Matrix Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am attempting to replicate Excel's top/bottom 10% conditional formatting functionality using a Power BI matrix visual. Data is Likert scale survey responses, and to evaluate, I am calculating the percent of disagreeability for each question using a measure (DAX code below).

```
    Calc Personnel = 
(CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Disagree")) +
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Slightly Disagree")) +
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Strongly Disagree"))
)
/
(
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Agree")) +
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Slightly Agree")) +
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Strongly Agree")) +
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Disagree")) +
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Slightly Disagree")) +
CALCULATE(
    Counta(data[My unit of assignment is:]),
    Filter(data,data[There are an adequate number of personnel assigned to my unit to perform the mission.]="Strongly Disagree"))
)
```

I would like to have the matrix visual look like the Excel table (see image below), but I have not stumbled upon the DAX code that will allow me to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Additionally, if there is another approach to calculating the percent of disagreeability for each question, I am willing to listen to all suggestions.

[image: Excel Top/Bottom 10% Cond Format]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the conditional formating for the visual?